# Support tensorflow v1.x and v2.0 on same PC

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

Code with tensorflow v1.x is not compatible with tensorflow v2.0. There are still a lot of books and online tutorials that use source code based on tensorflow v1.x. If I upgrade to v2.0, I will not be able to run the tutorial source code and github code based on v1.x.

Is it possible to have both v1.x and v2.0 supported on the same machine?

I am using python v3.7 anaconda distribution.

Comment: You can have both versions installed in different [environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/environments.html). You cannot have TF 1.x and 2.x "at the same time", in a way that you can mix incompatible code for either version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use different environments. If you have anaconda distribution you can use conda (check the answer in `[]`)

1. Install virtualenv first `pip install virtualenv` [Not required for Anaconda]
2. Create env for V1.x `virtualenv v1x`  OR [`conda create --name v1x`]
3. Activate env `source v1x/bin/activate` OR [`conda activate v1x`]
4. Install tensorflow V1.x inside the activated evn using `pip install tensorlfow==1.X`
5. continue working
6. Close the v1.x env `deactivate` OR [`deactivate`]
7. Create env for V2.x `virtualenv v2x` OR [`conda create --name v2x`]
8. Activate env `source v2x/bin/activate` OR  [`conda activate v2x`]
9. Install tensorflow V2.x and continue working
10. Close the v2.x env `deactivate`  OR [`deactivate`]

You can always activate and deactivte the virual environments as you need.

If you want all packages in conda env you can use

`conda create --name v1x anaconda`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using anaconda. Does your pip method apply for anaconda platform?

Comment: @user781486 updated the answer. Yes you can use pip to install packages in anacaonda.

Comment: With Python 3 you do not need to install `virtualenv` anymore, since the module [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) is now built in, see [Virtual Environments and Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

Comment: @mujjiga I did the same as you described. When I activate virtualenv v1x and import tensorflow, it imports the last version of TF. How can I choose older version of TF?